# Tossing coins - symmetry probability

Tags: probability

> Player A tosses a coin 203 times and player B tosses a coin 101 times, what is the probability that the number of heads obtained by A is twice that obtained by B?

My approach: Number of heads obtained by B in 101 times will be half of those obtained in 202 times (?) thus we can solve it by symmetry - 2p+x=1, hence p+x/2 = 0.5(ans). But I am not sure if the first claim holds or how to prove it.

Comment: I suggest:  just do it case by case.  The winning outcomes would be $(0,0), (2,1), (4,2), \cdots (2H, H)\cdots, (202,101)$.  Just add the probabilities of those up.

Comment: Possibly, not sure though

Comment: Such precise outcomes arue going to be very rare indeed.  Try it for smaller numbers, like if $B$ tosses $10$ times, and $A$, $21$.  Anyway, I think summing up the cases is your best bet.  You'll want to use a program of some sort.

Comment: Just to illustrate:  of the winning pairs, the most likely is that $A$ gets $102$ and $B$ gets $51$. That has probability $0.055794676\times 0.078808951=0.00439712$, so it's extremely unlikely.  The other winning pairs are even less likely.

Comment: oh, so its going to be far far less than 0.5, tending to 0 you mean, intuitively

Comment: For comparison purposes, I get the final answer to be $0.032318629$   But I should add that I threw the program together hastily and did not debug it carefully.    Note that, as an approximation, you can effectively ignore cases in which $B$ gets $<40$ or $>60$.

Comment: Is this an assigned problem?  If so, is the problem composer looking for an exact numerical answer or a closed form expression (presumably) involving a summation?

Comment: @lulu approximating the (exact) sum gives the same value (Mathematica can compute the exact value, but it's not a very informative fraction).

Comment: @ClementC.  Not informative at all, I agree.  It's nice, however, to see which terms matter.  As I mentioned, only a handful of terms actually contribute to the final.

Comment: @lulu w.a. shows the same result ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=0.5%5E304*sum_%28k%3D0%29%5E%28101%29+%28%28203%29+choose+2k%29*%28101+choose+k%29)). It seems that Vamdermode's Identity doesn't help.